# My login page will allow any credentials to login

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

My login page will allow any credentials to login and I cannot figure out for the life of me why.

**Code:**

```
<?php require 'db_conn.php'?>
<?php
session_start();
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
if ($conn === false) {
    die ('Failed to connect to Database');
}
if ( !isset($_POST['inputUsername'], $_POST['inputPassword']) ) {
    die ('Please fill both the username and password field!');
}
$usersql = "SELECT User, Password FROM Users WHERE User = '" . $_POST['inputUsername'] . "' AND Password = '" . $_POST['inputPassword'] . "'";
$userstmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $usersql);
if ($userstmt) {
   $userrow = sqlsrv_fetch_array($userstmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
   session_regenerate_id();
   $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
   $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
   $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
   header('Location: home.php');
}
else {
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = FALSE;
    header('Location: login.php');
}

sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Instead of only checking if the query succeeded (`if ($userstmt)`)  you also need to check if there was any results, `$userrow`. Or by using `sqlsrv_num_rows()`.

Comment: Please check the result of query of $userstmt. Please print the value of $userstmt

Comment: You should also not store passwords in **plain text**, that is highly inapropriate! Would you like for others to ever see your password? No? Didn't think so either ;-)

Comment: Amd in addition you should use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Yeah I know about passwords being in plain text and SQL Injections, this is purely test data to get my head around it before I use live data.

Comment: A couple of links to back up what has already been said [How to use PHP's password_hash to hash and verify passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-phps-password-hash-to-hash-and-verify-passwords) and [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: @Jackawan Be careful with the `user` column, because `USER` is a reserved keyword and `WHERE user = 'some_value'` can be very tricky.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please check result of userrow and not check userstmt value

```
$usersql = "SELECT User, Password FROM Users WHERE User = '" . $_POST['inputUsername'] . "' AND Password = '" . $_POST['inputPassword'] . "'";
$userstmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $usersql);
    $userrow = sqlsrv_fetch_array($userstmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);

if (count($userrow) > 0 ) {
    session_regenerate_id();
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
    $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
    header('Location: home.php');
}
else {
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = FALSE;
    header('Location: login.php');

}
```

Comment: Now it doesn't let anyone login.

Comment: please sir can you print the value of $userrow

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar You need to check the `$userstmt` before any other function call.  Executing `count($userrow)` is an error, because `$userrow` can be `false`. And injecting user input into a statement can lead to SQL injection issues.

Answer (score 1):

The actual reason for this unexpected behaviour is that you are checking the result from the `sqlsrv_query()` call, not the data returned from the executed statement.

You also need to consider the following:

- You are using `user` in your `SELECT` statement and in your `WHERE` clause. `USER` is a [reserved T-SQL keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) which returns the database user name, so you need to use `[user]` instead.
- Use parameters in your statement to prevent possible SQL injection issues. As is mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-query?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks), the `sqlsrv_query()` function *is well-suited for one-time queries and should be the default choice to execute queries unless special circumstances apply. This function provides a streamlined method to execute a query with a minimum amount of code. The sqlsrv_query function does both statement preparation and statement execution, and can be used to execute parameterized queries.*
- Use `sqlsrv_has_rows()` to check if the result set has one or more rows.
- As an additional note, do not store passwords in plain text, use hashed passwords.

The next example (based on the code in the question) is a possible solution to your problem:

```
<?php require 'db_conn.php'?>
<?php
// Session
session_start();

// Connection
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
if ($conn === false) {
    die ('Failed to connect to Database');
}

// Statement
if (!isset($_POST['inputUsername'], $_POST['inputPassword']) ) {
    die ('Please fill both the username and password field!');
}
$usersql = "SELECT [User], [Password] FROM Users WHERE [User] = ? AND [Password] = ?";
$userparams = array($_POST['inputUsername'], $_POST['inputPassword']);
$userstmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $usersql, $userparams);

// 
if ($userstmt === false) {
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = FALSE;
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit;
}   
if (!sqlsrv_has_rows($userstmt)) {
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = FALSE;
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit;
}

// 
$userrow = sqlsrv_fetch_array($userstmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
session_regenerate_id();
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['id'] = $id;

sqlsrv_free_stmt($userstmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn);
header('Location: home.php');
?>
```

Comment: Now it doesn't let any login, it just keeps redirecting back to log in page.

Comment: @Jackawan We need a debug information - 1) What does `var_dump($userstmt)` return; 2) What are the data types of `User` and `Password` columns; 3) What are the actual values of `$_POST['username']` and `$_POST['inputPassword']` array items; 4) Possible unicode issues, if you miss `CharacterSet"=>"UTF-8"` option in the `sqlsrv_connect()` call.

Answer (score 0):

`sqlsrv_query()` function returns statement resource which is a mixed adat type. It will false if there is an error in the query.

`if ($userstmt)` returns always true.